# Pigpio equivalent of GPIO's event_detected() function?

Tags: python, pigpio

Is there an pigpio equivalent to GPIO's event_detected() function?  I need something that is constantly watching for a button press.  The code I currently have doesn't consistently detect it (python sample code below).

```
import pigpio
pi = pigpio.pi()
y = 1
while pi.read(21) == 1:
    y = y + 1
    print(y)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pigpio term is [callback](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#callback).

```py
def cbf(gpio, level, tick):
   print(gpio, level, tick)

cb1 = pi.callback(22, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, cbf)

cb2 = pi.callback(4, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE)

cb3 = pi.callback(17)

print(cb3.tally())

cb3.reset_tally()

cb1.cancel() # To cancel callback cb1.
```

There is also [wait_for_edge](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#wait_for_edge) but I would prefer callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  This is the final code I wound up using in case anyone else has a similar question.

```
import pigpio
pi = pigpio.pi()

def cbf(gpio, level, tick):
    print("Button pressed")
cb1 = pi.callback(21, pigpio.FALLING_EDGE, cbf) # FALLING_EDGE, RISING_EDGE, or EITHER_EDGE

y = 1

while True:
    y = y + 1
    print(y)
```

Comment: Have a look at [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py).